# AMD Phenom II X4 965 stuck at 800Mhz on GA-78LMT-USB3 Rev5 motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, amd-phenom

- I am on firmware "FA", which is the latest and only one available for
  this motherboard.
- My CPU is listed on the list of compatible
  processors.
- There is very little load on my system.
- I have a good PSU.
- Cool & Quiet is off in the BIOS.
- Power options in windows are on "Performance"

Still the CPU does not go much beyond 800MHz, I say "much" because under load sometimes the cores go to 1000MHz or so. However the max possible on the cores is 3.4Ghz.

How can I fix this?

## UPDATE:

I was relying on a tool called "TMonitor" to show me the real-time MHz. However I do not trust it anymore, since even when running a benchmark the tool would not show much variance from 800MHz, sometimes even going down, whereas I could hear the CPU fans getting loud. I tried this running geekbench and got a similar score to others with the same CPU (around 6000 for multi-core)

So I tried a couple of other tools HWMonitor and HWInfo, and both show the real-time speeds as 3.4Ghz. Which is weird in itself, because even when I set windows power mode to "power saver", and turn on "cool & quiet" those two tools still say the idle speed on each core is 3.4Ghz, so basically I am confused.

Comment: Enter the bios and load default settings, see if this makes a difference.

Comment: This is while running windows? And you say it does go up to 1000 MHz sometimes, while under load... so it's *not stuck*... I don't think it's broken (*yet* but keep trying ;-) sounds like it's working. Tried any cpu intensive tasks?

Comment: As @Xen2050 stated your CPU may not be broken. In its idle state Windows doesn't need that much CPU power to keep breathing. Try benchmark softwares (like AIDA64 or http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm) and see how your CPU is doing before you try to fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find if there is a ErP (also known as Energy-Related Products Directive) in BIOS and disable.
Read this post : http://www.overclockers.com/step-guide-overclock-amd-phenom/